# Fetch() a local json file from public folder return an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

My folder is as follows :

- public > myJson.json
- src > App.js and MyComponent.js

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import MyComponent from "./mycomponent";

const App: React.FC = () => {

  fetch("public/myJson.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));

  return <MyComponent>;
};

export default App;
```

MyJson.json

```
[
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
  },
  {
    "a": "aa",
    "b": "bb"
  }
]
```

console error (with .json()):

```
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR :

- fetch with headers

```
headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
```

- fetch("../public/myJson.json")
- const response = await fetch()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
fetch("public/myJson.json")
```

to just

```
fetch("/myJson.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

with .text() :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/0.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script><script src="/main.93e6b12087c32cb33380.hot-update.js"></script></body>
</html>
```